# Display all list of date to columns that given by between date condition

Tags: mysql

I have a question about my problem in [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40606184/display-day-or-date-as-column-in-mysql)

I think my question is to complicated before,

So, I created a new question for simply :

```
WHERE DATE(e.created_at) BETWEEN DATE('2016-11-13') AND DATE('2016-11-15')
```

I need the format like this,

```
+-----------+----+----+----+----------------
   another  | 13 | 14 | 15 | another again
+-----------+----+----+----+----------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
 SELECT ....,
    IF(DATE((e.created_at)= str_to_date("2016-11-13","%Y-%m-%d"),1,0) as '13',
    IF(DATE((e.created_at)= str_to_date("2016-11-14","%Y-%m-%d"),1,0) as '14',
    IF(DATE((e.created_at)= str_to_date("2016-11-15","%Y-%m-%d"),1,0) as '15',
    ......
```

Comment: How about entire day in a month, 1-31

Comment: you mean you want to display 1/0 for all days?